# JPA query filter on concatenated fields

Tags: hibernate, jpa, jpa-2.0, criteria-api

I want to query my "customers" table using "name + surname" string as a key.

Name and surname are stored in different fields.

So my query would be:

```
SELECT 
   * 
FROM 
   customers 
WHERE 
   CONCAT(name,' ',surname) LIKE '%term%' 
   OR CONCAT(surname,' ',name) LIKE '%term%'
```

However, I can't do that, my query is a JPA2 **criteria query**. Something like:

```
CriteriaBuilder cb = getEntityManager().getCriteriaBuilder();
            CriteriaQuery cq = cb.createQuery();
            Root<Customer> from = cq.from(Customer.class);
            cq.select(from);

            Predicate whereClause = cb.or(
                cb.like(from.<String>get("name"), "%"+ r +"%"),
                cb.like(from.<String>get("surname"), "%"+ r +"%"),
            );

            cq.where(whereClause);      
            TypedQuery<Customer> query = getEntityManager().createQuery(cq);
            list = query.getResultList();
```

How can I filter my result set by the combination of name and surname, please?

Answer (score 25, accepted):

Use [CriteriaBuilder.concat(Expression, Expression)](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/persistence/criteria/CriteriaBuilder.html#concat%28javax.persistence.criteria.Expression,%20javax.persistence.criteria.Expression%29):

```
Expression<String> exp1 = cb.concat(from.<String>get("name"), " ");
exp1 = cb.concat(exp1, from.<String>get("surname"));
Expression<String> exp2 = cb.concat(from.<String>get("surname"), " ");
exp2 = cb.concat(exp2, from.<String>get("name"));
Predicate whereClause = cb.or(cb.like(exp1, "%"+ r +"%"), cb.like(exp2, "%"+ r +"%"));
```

Comment: If your database supports the CONCAT_WS (concat with separator) you can do something like:

  Expression<String> nameConcat = cb.function(
                    "CONCAT_WS",
                    String.class,
                    cb.literal(" "),
                    from.<String>get("name"),
                    from.<String>get("surname"));

I wanted to have a delimiter in my concat, but some of the fields were empty or null and chaining these together would add spaces in my concat that I didn't want when there were blanks.